# nHibernate ProxyFactory issues

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I am setting up my first nHibernate project.  I have created a simple web form that accepts a name and an id however, I keep on getting the following error:

The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured.
Initialize 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory configuration section with one of the available NHibernate.ByteCode providers.
Example:
NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
Example:
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

I have already added the references to both Castle and LinFu to my project.  I have also configured the web.config to the following:

```
<section name="nhibernate" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
```

Can you tell me what is going on?  I have tried everything.  Is it that I imported a lot of my mappings etc, from visualNHibernate?  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what proxy factory you intend to use, as for example:

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>`
```

And, furthermore, the cconfiguration you posted contains... nothing, please ensure to have a minimum configuration in place, without it you can't create the NH session factory.

Comment: Sorry, here is config: <nhibernate>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
    <add key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect"/>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=192.168.1.112, 1433;Initial Catalog=DGWG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pw;"/>
  </nhibernate>

Comment: @ric, so add the line I suggested in the reply ( for the proxy you want ) deploy the assembly needed and it will works

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that but still get the same error

Comment: <nhibernate xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=stuff;Initial Catalog=DGWG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>

  </nhibernate>

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working :(  I have exhausted most of my options.  I will continue trying and reading all the resources you have pointed me to. THAnks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper ProxyFactoryFactory and let NHibernate know what implementation should be used to create proxy objects. Fabio posted how to do it a while ago over at nhibernate.info: http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.html
I also strongly suggest to read the [documentation about configuration of NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic).

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory name="YourAppName">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
            Server=(local);initial catalog=nhibernate;Integrated Security=SSPI
        </property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the whole config: